# What does として mean in 「ペットとしてしいくするのはかんたんです。」?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I'm reading a JLPT N5 graded text (to practice reading with kanjis) and I understand all of it except for the following sentence:

> ペットとしてしいくするのはかんたんです。

I don't understand the として in that sentence. I looked it up on http://jgram.org and [it's listed as an N2 level expression](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=toshite), so I guess it's quite advanced. I read the definition ("indicates the capacity, role, or function of someone or something"), but I don't get how it fits into the sentence (I understand it as 'Breeding a pet is easy')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`〜として` in this sense is like you said:  in the role/function/capacity of.  You can often remember it `As (a) 〜`.  So in this sentence, it might be easier to understand if you translate this way.

> - ペットとして[飼育]{し・いく}するのは[簡単]{かん・たん}です。　→　Having/Raising/Keeping X (whatever animal) **as a pet** is easy.  (I think 飼育 is probably one of these definitions here more than "breeding", but without more context from the passage...  See comments below.)

Here are some other examples that might help:

> - あの人はがんばる会社員**として**よく知られている　→　That guy is well known **as a** hard-working employee.
> - これは母じゃなくて、友達として言いますけど．．．　→　I'm not telling you this as your mother, but **as a** friend...
> - 敵**として**扱う　→　Treat someone **as an** enemy

Comment: 飼育 for "having pet" is perfectly OK. It's not "raising" (if I believe my E-J dictionary tells me that "raise" is only used for livestock) here.

Comment: "Keeping" is one possible translation.

Comment: In my mind, "raising"/"having"/"keeping" an animal are pretty interchangeable in English.  Thoughts?

Comment: @broccoliforest your E-J dictionary is wrong about "raise". You can most definitely raise a pet, like a hamster or a dog. You can even raise children. All of these are natural expressions -- at least in AmE.

Comment: Thank you. Raising children is OK too, but when it comes to animals, it says "of livestock". It seems I shouldn't trust them too much.